# Moment dates are parsed different in Mozilla and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, momentjs, mozilla

I have an issue with dates in Mozilla, I am using fullcalendar plugin for angularJs in my project. While using the moment dates, Chrome seems to be working fine but Mozilla seems breaking. I am using Timezones with the moment. Many blogs and posts seems to mention the format of moment dates while having cross browser issues.

Here it is,

```
  console.log(moment(new Date('2017-02-28T18:30:00')).format('dddd-MMM DD,YYYY'));
```

> Mozilla : Tuesday-Feb 28,2017
>
> Chrome : Wednesday-Mar 01,2017

I am really stuck with this, and I have seen post about mentioning the format with the moment dates, but I have used the format in the above sample but it fails to return the desired output. On the other hand Chrome is returning the correct result, what am I doing wrong ?

If you need any details please leave a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `moment(new Date('2017-02-28T18:30:00'))` use [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) instead (since your input is in ISO 8601 format).

As moment [parsing docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) says:

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

Here a working sample:

```js
console.log(moment('2017-02-28T18:30:00').format('dddd-MMM DD,YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

If your input is UTC use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

```
moment.utc('2017-02-28T18:30:00')
```

If your input is in a given timezone (e.g. `Asia/Calcutta`) use [`moment.tz(..., String);`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/)

```
moment.tz('2017-02-28T18:30:00', 'Asia/Calcutta')
```

By default moment parses string in local time, you need to know timezone of your input. Note the moment has [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/), [`utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/), and [`tz(String)`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) methods to change timezone of a moment object.

Comment: I have tried this before, now the dates fall to 28 Feb. I need it like 1st March.

Comment: Try moment(string).utc().format('dddd-MMM DD,YYYY')

Comment: @Jaychandran why `2017-02-28T18:30:00` should be interpreted as `2017-03-01`? Maybe you have to add details to your question.

Comment: I have added the detail in calendar for that date, I am using Timezone information for adding the details. So how should I parse this string to my native zone, I have used moment timezone. Chrome gave me the right date, so I sticked with the option until Mozilla broken.

Comment: @Jaychandran I've updated my answer, hope that it helps. Note that you have to know how you have to treat your input string. Does it represents local time? Or UTC? Or a given timezone?

Answer (score 2):

You are converting a JS Date to a MomentJS date so I can only assume Firefox parses the JS date differently.

With MomentJS you should be able to simply replace your code:

```
moment(new Date('2017-02-28T18:30:00')).format('dddd-MMM DD,YYYY')
```

with:

```
moment('2017-02-28T18:30:00').format('dddd-MMM DD,YYYY')
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: Have tried this one, but how will we parse that to 1st March like the Chrome did

Comment: Are you sure that chrome was parsing `'2017-02-28T18:30:00'` as March 1st instead of another string? Because just looking at the date itself I can't see how that would ever be parsed as a day later unless you add a day to it.

Comment: Yea sure, I am using Timezone in other place

Answer (score 0):

if you use ***angularjs***, it's easier to use `filter`.

```
$filter('date')('2017-02-28T18:30:00', "dd/MM/yyyy");
```